# When i take photo in android app using image view, it rotates and cant get path

Tags: java, android

When i take photo in android app using image view, it rotates and cant get photo path. but when image not rotates path become store in string..
how can i fix cemra oriantation and..
How can i handle out of memory error for bitmap.

Comment: Take a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

use this code to display bitmap from path

```
Imageview.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromeResource(selectedImagePath, 200, 200));
```